# How to read a file in webapp without placing it in Tomcat's /bin folder

Tags: tomcat, servlets, file-io

I am trying to read a file from Tomcat container on doGet method using File descriptor.
The program when executed looks for "sample.txt" under tomcat bin folder. I dont want my resource file to be part of Tomcat bin. How do i read the file in a better approach which gives me flexibility in defining my resource directory. I am also trying to read the file from POJO deployed as helper classes in Tomcat. 
Can i also configure classpath in tomcat to look for the file in different directory?
Any pointers will be of great help.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("Sample Text");
    RSAPublicCertificate rsa = new RSAPublicCertificate();
    out.print(rsa.getCertificate());
    File file = new File("sample.txt");
    out.print(file.getAbsolutePath());
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

}

D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\bin\sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed avoid using `new File()` and `new FileInputStream()` with a relative path. For background information, see also [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream/2308388#2308388).

Just use an absolute path like

```
File file = new File("/absolute/path/to/sample.txt");
// ...
```

or add the given path to the classpath as `shared.loader` property of  `/conf/catalina.propeties`

```
shared.loader = /absolute/path/to
```

so that you can just get it from the classpath as follows

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.txt");
// ...
```